# Expanding hidden content when stepping with search on page (ctrl+f) in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have some divs hidden until expanded (not using display: none;), so they are searchable. I want to be able to expand the active div if it contains somethings that's searched for.

In Firefox/Edge it was possible to do something to that effect using selectionchange event on the document. This doesn't not however seem to work with chrome. Is there a way to do something that will have a similar effect in chrome? The search finds the text but doesnt trigger the selectionchange event.